# Repeater: javascript to button in itemlist via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, databound

I've got a repeater with an itemlist, it get's data via C#/sql and a databind.
I then want to add onclick javascript to my 'deleteNewsButton' in the itemlist.
Im guessing that i have to use OnItemDataBound?

Heres my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="newsListRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="deleteConfirm_Databound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("id") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("title") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("tags") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("author") %></td>
                <td style="width:100px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "time", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %></td>
                <td style="width:110px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="editNewsButton" runat="server" OnCommand="editNewsButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Rediger" />
                    <asp:Button ID="deleteNewsButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Slet" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

EDIT:
How would i bind a paramter from behind code, to my 'deleteNewsButton' controllers.
It needs to be done from behind code...

Comment: are you asking for suggestion...for getting some error.. ?

Comment: Just made a edit... with some clarification

Comment: wohhaa...still question is unclear...

Comment: I want to add an attribute to my button 'deleteNewsButton' from the behind code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for a repeater item databound event you need to use RepeaterItemEventArgs instead of RepeaterItem

```
protected void deleteConfirm_Databound(object sender, RepeaterItem e)
```

becomes

```
protected void deleteConfirm_Databound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
```

You might also want a null check for that control:

```
LinkButton button = (LinkButton)e.FindControl("deleteNewsButton");  
if(button != null) {
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +  
        "confirm('Er du sikker på du vil slette: " +  DataBinder.Eval(e.DataItem, "id") + "')"); 
}
```

You may also consider making a common javascript function for the confirm box, and then just calling it from your button.

aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmFunction(id)
{
   return confirm('Er du sikker på du vil slette: ' +  id); 
}
</script>
```

codebehind

```
LinkButton button = (LinkButton)e.FindControl("deleteNewsButton");  
if(button != null) {
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirmFunction(" + DataBinder.Eval(e.DataItem, "id") + ");"); 
}
```

Comment: Note that this was in response to the pre-edit question, so it was relevant at one point. I am posting this to avoid downvotes from those late to the party ;)

Comment: I think you are on the right track.
But i cant use e.FindControl (error: Does not contain a definition for FindControl)?

And the same for DataItem

Comment: I found the problem, its a button not a link button.
And have to do: e.Item.Findcontrol, else it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

add an onclientclick event  eg.

```
<asp:Button ID="deleteNewsButton"  
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you really want to Delete this record ?')" 
runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Slet" />
```